# vim syntastic: <form> proprietary attribute "novalidate"

Tags: html, vim, syntastic

I have following vim plugins installed:

- `Plugin 'othree/html5.vim'`
- `Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'`

however, having following html chunk:

```
<form novalidate>
</form>
```

shows:

```
<form> propritary attribute "novalidate"
```

To prevent error I have to explicitly say (in my `~/.vimrc`):

```
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors=["<form> proprietary attribute \"novalidate\""]
```

Still I thought that `othree/html5.vim` plugin does the job here.

Why is it not so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that `html5.vim` plugin does nothing related to `html tidy` at all and nothing in its `README` supports that idea. It only extends Vim's built-in HTML support with various HTML5 features.

Syntastic being another plugin, it must be customized independently.